# Potential generated by induced electric field

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we have some solenoid with time varying current and a wire with radius of solenoid  tightly wound around it. I was also told that half wire is made from different material than other half so that resistance in both half is different . can potential be calculated in such a field? I know that induced electric field is non conservative so potential will be bit problematic to calculate , is this possible?

Comment: non-conservative = no potential.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Wait, is that correct?  A non-conservative fluctuating electric field has associated electric potentials (scalar and vector), right?  They probably are not easily modeled, but from a fundamental E&M point of view, dissipation does not preclude the existence of an electric potential (unless I am missing something).